# Azure web app integration with data lake

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-data-lake

I am creating a python web job which runs the script to convert excel data stored in data lake into csv. The script is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('path/excel file in data lake', 'sheet1',header=0)

df.to_csv('path/empty csv file in DL', encoding='utf-8')
```

The above code is giving an OS error :-

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
>   'adl://DLstorename.azuredatalakestore.net/filename.xlsx'

Can anyone suggest how should I connect my webjob with data lake so that it recognizes the filepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anna mentioned in the above answer, I used azure data lake library with python to connect to my data lake store.

I installed this library for the webjob using the cmd console of KUDU services (which is available under Development tools section in Advanced Tools of the webapp) and did the following changes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(adl.open('folder name/excel file name in data lake'),'sheet1',header=0)

df.to_csv('folder name/empty csv file name in DL', encoding='utf-8')
```

This did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas isn't able to work directly with Azure Data Lake Store. Instead, try using the ADLS python module to connect to ADLS to get the document and, once you're done with it in pandas, use it again to save it back.

http://azure-datalake-store.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Hope that helps!